# Django model inheritance primary keys

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I am using Django model inheritance. Similar to the example [from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Since "Each model corresponds to its own database table", how are primary keys assigned? Do I have any guarantee that there are no collisions between the Restaurant `id` values and the Place `id` values? How strong is this guarantee (Will the DB enforce it)?

Comment: Each `Restaurant` will first make a record at the table for `Place`. Then it will make a recod for the table for `Restaurant` with the same primary key. Since that primary key is also a `ForeignKey` to the `Place` model.

Comment: Thanks Willem. Does Django tell the db to use the fk as the pk? Post as answer if you want.